# Invalid JSON primitive JQUERY

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

i am using this function to get data from my db using web service in asp.net & c#
this my function

```
 function test(MsId) {
                    var options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/web_service/Services.asmx/GetData",
                            type: "GET",
                            dataType: "json",
                            data: {
                                'MsId': MsId
                            },
                            contentType: "application/Json; Charset= Utf-8",
                            success: function (data) {
                                var list = "";
                                $.each(data.d[0][0], function (index, item) {
                                    list += "<div class='active'><div class='direct-chat-infos'><span class='direct-chat-name float-left'>" + item.CompleteName + "</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;" + item.Status_Status + "</div><span class='direct-chat-timestamp float-left text-sm'>" + new Date(parseInt(item.Status_Date.substr(6))) + "</span><br /></div>";
                                });
                                $("#List").html(list);
                            },
                            error: function (response) {
                                alert(response);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
```

but she give me this error i am using incrypting id(picture)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNViS.png)

Comment: No way for us to know why your server is returning that error.

Comment: @Taplar i think i am use id decrypted?

Comment: Absolutely no idea.  We don't know anything about how that endpoint is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

$.ajax doesn't convert data to json itself, you need to do it

Change

```
data: { 'MsId': MsId },
```

To

```
data: JSON.stringify({ 'MsId': MsId }),
```

Also note I've never seen capitals used in `"application/json"`

Comment: {"Message":"Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027MsId\u0027.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethod(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler

Comment: So how are you calling the function? Check what Msld is before the request is made

Comment: iam calling my function like this test(Id);

Comment: Ok ...is `id` defined and valid value? Your error is implying no value sent

Comment: thank you, i think the problem is in incrypted id because where i am sending id not decrypted working fine :(